# Calling Google WebApp from TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, cors, tampermonkey

I can't get a response from a TamperMonkey script calling my published google script web app.

my doGet is simple:

```
function doGet(e){
    var params = JSON.stringify(e);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}
```

I've tried with JQuery getJSON, and with

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: url + encodeURIComponent(name),
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

I've tried with ?callback=? and also without.

I can't seem to escape the three known problems, either:

- Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
- The JQueryXXX is not defined, which led me to suggestions to remove the ?callback=
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin that's not in the header

I've tried adding a synchronous javascript call, without tampermonkey:

```
<script>
function dosend(){
        var SCRIPT_URL = // the google exec url

       var url = SCRIPT_URL + "?test="+"temp"+"&test2="+"temp2";

       var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
       xmlHttp.send( null );
       alert( xmlHttp.responseText);
}
</script>
```

This call somewhat works, I can see that there's another call to google acounts ServiceLogin (which fails, that's a separate problem though).

How do I get TamperMonkey / JQuery to successfully make the call to the google web app?

Comment: The `doGet()` function should not be returning anything from HTML Service.  You need to use `ContentService`

Comment: I've tried ContentService with a bunch of alternative mime types, no success.